# Triggering ASP.Net MVC Bundling from commandline

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to trigger the bundling (System.Web.Optimization) process in ASP.Net MVC from the command line to get the minified file?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your request? We want to do the exact same thing, and we're stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because is System.Web.Optimization a library and you would need some wrapper to run in in the console. But you can find many other console tools which can do the same thing.

Online minifier: http://refresh-sf.com/

Console minifier: http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/

Other tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29

Comment: that was sad to learn. We are actually using ASP.Net bundling, and I wanted to reuse it someplace else as well instead of duplicating stuff.

Comment: @JernejNovak, what other console tools? Can you suggest one or two?